# Stop Sync with Remote WebSite on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

As you might know,Visual Studio 2008 has "Copy Web Site to Remote Server" feature. But the problem is every time I open it waits to sync websites (local website and remote website) and makes me wait.

Is there any way to close auto sync on Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've found a tool named Dispatch which can be downloaded [here](http://www.dispatchasp.net/)
But the problem is it's for Visual Studio not Web Developer Express because Express edition doesn't support add-ins and it's for paid which means you have to pay for that and that's what I don't desire :) I hope it works for you guys.